# Move svg element via Drag and Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am currently working on a project where I am placing an svg text element wrapped in a group on a template. I need the user to both drag the element around (which I have working) and move SELECTED element via arrow keys. The code below is what I have been working on for a while now and the element seems to jump right and down by several pixels at a time. Something is just not right. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
function drag(r) {
 r.drag(move, start, stop);         
}

var move = function() {
 this.attr({style:'cursor: grabbing;'});        
}

var start = function() {

}

var stop = function() {
 this.attr({style:'cursor: pointer;'}); 
 xyc(this);
}

function xyc(svg){
 var bb = svg.getBBox();
 console.log('New: x: ' + bb.x + ' y: '+ bb.y);
 keymove(svg,bb.x,bb.y);
}

function keymove(g,bx,by) {
console.log('New: x: ' + bx + ' y: '+ by);
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

    if(e.keyCode == 39) {//right
        g.attr('kx', bx+=1);
        g.attr('ky', by);
        g.attr({transform:'translate('+ g.attr('kx') + ',' +   g.attr('ky') + ')'});
        xyc(g);             
    }else if(e.keyCode == 37) {//left
        g.attr('kx', bx-=1);
        g.attr('ky', by);
        g.attr({transform:'translate('+ g.attr('kx') + ',' +  g.attr('ky') + ')'});
        xyc(g);
    }       
    else{
        return; 
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: getBBox gets the position post transform so you're adding the x, y position a second time when you set the transform.